# Getting error while running npm start in the cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

My `package.json` file looks like this-

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

The project is made using **create-react-app** but when I am trying to execute the start scripts, getting mentioned error `"npm ERR! missing script: start"`

Comment: How you run the project ?

Comment: you should use `npm run start` rather than `npm start`

Comment: `npm ERR! missing script: start`: seems like you are not in the right directory. `cd` to the project directory and then run command `npm start` or `npm run start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says, you are in a wrong directory... Try double checking your directory also if your in a right directory make sure the file is saved if its saved then try closing and opening your terminal or vscode.